# How to update selection with new data in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to edit the data of created circles in D3. Below my code is pasted of me creating a lot of circles based on some data from `graphData`.

Supposed I'd want to re-arrange my circles Y position with a new dataset, by transitioning them to their new destinations. How would perform this task? I've tried using `attr`.("cy", `function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d))}` ) to update my Y-coordinates by adding `data(graphData[i], function(d){return d;}`) with my new data, but this does not work.

You can take a look at my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RBr8h/1/

Instead of the for-loop in the following code I've created circles on 2 ticks of my X-axis. I have 3 sets of data and I've used to of them in the example in the fiddle. I'd like to able to use the 3rd dataset instead of the 2 first ones on both circles.

```
            var circle;
            for(var i = 0;i < graphData.length;i++){
                circle = SVGbody
                    .selectAll("circle")
                    .data(graphData[i], function(d){return d;})
                    .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("cx",xScale(0))
                        .attr("cy", yScale(minAxisY))
                        .attr("r",4)
                        .style('opacity', 0)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(1000)
                        .attr("cx", function(d){
                            return spreadCircles(i);
                        })
                        //.attr("cy", function (d, i){ return yScale(i); })
                        .style('opacity', 1)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(1500)
                            .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d))} );
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: When updating, you need to handle the update selection, not just the enter selection. More in [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) for example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried applied an update to my fiddle using, the enter to create my circles, and an update to try and move their position, although my results are incredibly weird. I've also tried applying the solution of FernOfTheAnders below, and it doesn't work in my fiddle.

Comment: It would be something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RBr8h/8/). I've changed your data matching and added a transition to make it clearer what's happening.

Comment: I apply the same to my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/RBr8h/9/
But it acts differently. Is it because of the fact that I'm using loops to create and update them?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you didn't handle the exit selection there so no nodes were removed -- http://jsfiddle.net/RBr8h/10/ Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Almost, I know I didnt handle the the exit selection. I  have tried both. And the fiddle you posted just know almost does what it is supposed to. It puts data on the 2nd tick, but there's nothing on the first tick. If you look at the top of my code I have graphData1 and graphData2. They both have 2 arrays pushed onto them. When loading graphdata1, the first array is shown on the first tick, and the second array is shown on the second tick. However when loading graphData2, circles are only shown on the second tick. You can see on the animation that everything is moved to the second tick. Why?

Comment: Here's a picture example of what I want. http://puu.sh/80BNe.png

Comment: Well your loop is running without delay, so only the last iteration and update of circles will have a visible effect.

Comment: Okay, so am I supposed to add a delay after a transition is being executed (at the end of the for-loop)?

Comment: If you want the circles to transition through the different data sets, yes.

Answer (score 2):

To put some flesh on Lars comment, here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xFj5W/) leveraging the enter/update/exit pattern to help you out. I have altered and simplified your code (and data) just enough to demonstrate the principle.

```
function updateCircles(dataset,color) {
    var circle = SVGbody
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset, function(d) { return d; });

    circle
        .exit()
        .transition().duration(750)
        .attr("r", 0)
        .remove();

    circle
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

    circle
        .attr("cx",function(d){return xScale(100);})
        .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d))})
        .attr("r",0)
        .transition().duration(1500)
        .attr("r",5)
        .style("fill", color);
};
```

[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/398cs/) with data keyed off by index...so, circles just have their position updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. It made a lot of things much clearer for me. However, I must say I'm still having problems, since I don't want to remove the current set of circles and add new ones with new data. I'd like to transition the old to the new positions without removing them, only moving them.

Also I tried using your solution in my own code and it doesn't seem to work. The section where you use `exit` and `remove`, if I remove that, the new circles appear on top of the old ones, so I can see both. If I add the remove, only 3-4 dots appear, very random.

Comment: Here's the fiddle of my code now with what I'm trying to do. Transitioning the old circles to new destinations based on a new dataset: http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/RBr8h/2/

And here's a fiddle using your posted solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/RBr8h/3/

With your solution there's nothing on the first tick of the x-axis.
You can also see the full graph at my website here if you think its of any use: http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/

To submit different datasets use the following strings in the input field: "CCL5" "CCR3" "CCR5"

Comment: The reason there is an if-else statement is because I have a certain animation upon the circles entering the first time. The 2nd time, when the data is changed, the are supposed to transition from their current position to the new position given by the new dataset.

Comment: What you need to do is to let the data binding be based on the index, which is the default: `.data(dataset)`. I am updating my response with the new fiddle.

Comment: Here is another version of the fiddle with buttons to see what's happening. I realized you can't really see what is going on, in the 2nd fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/RBr8h/5/ In this one, if you don't use `exit()` and `remove()`, you can see that both sets appear next to each other, but when you add the part with `exit()` and `remove()` the first part doesn't appear.

Comment: Why is it that this doesn't work when I apple it to my fiddle?
I have the codes for the update and the initializaion seperated, but I dont see what else I'm doing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/RBr8h/6/

I apply the same to on my website as well, it acts the same way. If you look on the transition it looks like it moves some elements from the first tick on the x-axis t the last one: http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/

Comment: What I really don't seem to understand is, why executing dataset1, ONLY shows the circles on the 2nd tick, and nothing on the first one: http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/RBr8h/7/ . If you can spot anything I might've done wrong, it'd be very much appreatiated..