# How do I use enter() correctly in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, exit, enter

I have some code that create a bunch of circles, updates those circles, removes some of the circles, and lastly I'd like to find out how to use the enter() correctly to add more circles to my current ones.

This is my code for creating circles when there are none:

```
        var circle = SVGbody
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(graphDataY/*, function(d){return d;}*/);

            circle.enter()
                .append("circle");

            circle
                .attr("cx",xScale(0))
                .attr("cy", yScale(minAxisY))
                .attr("r",4)
                .style('opacity', 0)
                .style("fill", colorCircles())
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
                //.attr("cy", function (d, i){ return yScale(i); })
                .style('opacity', 0.8)
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("cy", function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));} );
```

I use the following code to update my circles and remove the ones that aren't being used (sometimes that's the case):

```
var circle = SVGbody
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graphDataY);

circle
                .style("fill", colorCircles())
                .transition().duration(1000)
                .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
                .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));});

circle.exit()
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(300)
                        .style("opacity", 0)
                        .remove();
```

And when lastly, let's assume the last data i used had a length of 100, that means I currently have 100 circles displayed. If I used a new dataset with 120 of length, I use my update code to move the existing circle ( except for the exit().remove() ), and then I try to use the following to "create" the remaining circles out of the remaining unbound data (which in this case would be 20 circles remaining):

```
                circle.enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
                    .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(parseFloat(d));})
                    .style("opacity", 0)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("opacity", 1)
```

Comment: The main concept behind the enter/update/exit pattern is precisely to avoid writing code that branches out based on whether you are adding, updating or removing data/DOM elements. You really only need one code sequence, normally wrapped within a function. (The `.data` operator may require a key, depending on what you are updating). But, we have been there [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22913145/how-to-update-selection-with-new-data-in-d3). I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/398cs/2/) from that response with 2 new points for the green dataset to demonstrate my point.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Are you saying that that last bit of code doesn't do what you're expecting it to do?

Comment: Okay I actually get it now. But the reason why I have seperated the initial creation of the circles and when they are to be changed, is because I want different animations depending on what is being "executed" by the user. So if the data appear for the first time there is a certain animation, if new data is inserted, the circles move places afterwards. And in some cases perform a third or fourth type of animation. How would go through the same could, while performing the different actions? Is it still possible?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes, it when I use the last piece of code, it doesn't do anything, and it's similar to my initlial code (the first piece of code)

Comment: It looks like it should work. Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: I've edited my code a bit now. I've tried to use write it the way FernOfTheAndes showed me in a previous question. I think my problem lies in the way I'd like the circles to be animated and the fact that I haven't put in cx, cy AND r. r isn't added in my last code, so I assume D3 can't create the circles when a radius hasn't been set yet. I do have a question though which I will post in the next comment.

Comment: We'll start with a link to a piece code that I use in my code. http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/pj6sX/2/  When there currently are circles, this piece of code is running, updating the circles. I've posted my question in the fiddle as it will be easier to read the code at the same time. HEre's a link to website so you can see a live action of what I have explained in the fiddle: http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/ Thank you very much in advance, sir.